# How to generate bitcoin address from XPUB

Tags: bitcoin, xpub

How to generate bitcoin address from XPUB, I am looking for pointers on how to use an XPUB to generate addresses. I would like to perform address generation offline with the XPUB.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/98919/

Comment: Maybe the Bitcoin bible might help? → https://github.com/mrkskwsnck/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch04.asciidoc

Answer (score 0):

I сreated [a library](https://github.com/GemsGame/crypto-wallet-js) for bitcoin address generation from **xpub**.
After installation you can write:

Answer (score -1):

An Xpub key can be broken into 2 parts.

The first 32 bytes, is the key and the last 32 bytes is the chaincode.

You can use the key part to create addresses by hashing it with `ripemd160(sha256(key))` and then encoding the resulting 20 byte hash with Base58 for legacy P2PKH addresses or Bech32 for Segwit P2WPKH addresses.